# Is this the right way to run a `release` command for a Heroku Review app?

Tags: heroku, devops, hasura

I'm trying to configure a review app on Heroku. For every PR, I'd like to deploy and build the Dockerfile, then run my migrations command.

With the below configs, the Dockerfile deploys fine, and the app appears to work as intended.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM hasura/graphql-engine:v1.0.0-beta.4
ENV HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE=true
CMD graphql-engine \
    --database-url $DATABASE_URL \
    serve \
    --server-port $PORT
```

heroku.yml

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
```

app.json

```
{
  "name": "my_project",
  "formation": {
    "web": {
      "quantity": 1,
      "size": "free"
    }
  },
  "addons": [
    {
      "plan": "heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev",
      "options": { "version": "9.6" }
    }
  ],
  "scripts": {},
  "buildpacks": [],
  "stack": "container"
}
```

But, when I add (what I think is) the release script for migrations, the build fails.

heroku.yml with release script:

```
release:
  image: Dockerfile
  command:
    - cd ./migrations && ./hasura migrate apply --endpoint $(heroku info -s | grep web_url | cut -d= -f2)
```

This results in the build error:

```
=== Fetching app code...
=!= Couldn't find the release image configured for this app. Is there a matching run process?
```

I've also tried to add a `release` key to the `scripts` key in `app.json`, but this doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: Change `image: Dockerfile` to `image: web` and see if it works?

Comment: Did you ever find out an answer? I'm also using Hasura and encountering the same problem and none of the suggested answers work for me

Answer (score 2):

The `image` parameter shouldn't be the name of your Dockerfile. It should be another image that you built.

In your case, you have a single one:

```
web: Dockerfile
```

So you need to specify your release process type like this:

```
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - cd ./migrations && ./hasura migrate apply --endpoint $(heroku info -s | grep web_url | cut -d= -f2)
```

Giving you the full heroku.yml as follows:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - cd ./migrations && ./hasura migrate apply --endpoint $(heroku info -s | grep web_url | cut -d= -f2)
```

For more information, you can check out the official Heroku documentation on this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#release-configuring-release-phase